# How to use interpolation to pass value to a function as an argument

Tags: angular, typescript

How to insert the {{c.id}} argument into the function (instead of where it is listed 32)?

```
  <tr *ngFor="let c of myService.companyList">
    <td>{{c.name}}</td>
    <td>{{c.email}}</td>
    <td>{{c.password}}</td>
    <td> <input type="submit" value="click to remove" (click)="removeCompany(32)" (click)=/> </td>
    <td> <a href="">Click here to remove this company {{c.id}}</a></td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just:

```
(click)="removeCompany(c.id)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Within *ngFor pass your local variable with object value, in your case it will be c.id which holds the id

```
<tr *ngFor="let c of myService.companyList">
    <td>{{c.name}}</td>
    <td>{{c.email}}</td>
    <td>{{c.password}}</td>
    <td> <input type="submit" value="click to remove" (click)="removeCompany(c.id)" (click)=/> </td>
    <td> <a href="">Click here to remove this company {{c.id}}</a></td>
</tr>
```